# ExtJS рендеринг после загрузки данных

Tags: java, extjs

На странице надо отрисовать одну из двух иконок. `card.recurrentSupported` имеет тип `Boolean`. На входе `value == null`. После загрузки данных, `value == true, false` или `null`. В текущей реализации, на странице сначала отрисовывается иконка `fa close`, а через 0.5 секунды, после загрузки данных, если `value == true`, иконка перерисовывается на `fa-check`.

Как можно дождаться загрузки данных, а потом уже отрисовывать иконки?

`renderer: function` имеет дополнительные параметры `metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view`. Может можно с их помощью получить флаг о загрузке данных?

```
    items: [                
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Поддержка рекуррентов',
                bind: '{card.recurrentSupported}',
                renderer: function (value) {
                    return value != null && value ? '<i class="fa fa-check text-green"></i>' : '<i class="fa fa-close text-red"></i>';
                }
            },
        ]
```

Comment: удалите это из вашего кода `на странице сначала отрисовывается иконка fa close` ?

Comment: на странице обязательно должна быть одна из двух иконок, так что удалять  fa close не вариант.

Comment: Ваш комментарий противоречит вашим же требованиям `Как можно дождаться загрузки данных, а потом уже отрисовывать иконки?`

Comment: После загрузки данных, должна быть одна из двух иконок. А до загрузки, ни чего не должно быть. `if(данные_данные_загружены) return fa-check or fa close else return "";`

Comment: Так я вам и предложил убрать иконку, которая светится до загрузки данных.

Comment: `return value != null && value ? '<i class="fa fa-check text-green"></i>' : '';`.  А как в таком случае потом выводить иконку, когда данные подгрузятся и value будет равно false или null?

Comment: В смысле как? Точно также, как и сейчас выводится. Не надо спрашивать как код будет работать, если что то сделать - делайте и проверяйте, будет конкретная ошибка или проблема - спрашивайте.

Comment: я делал, проверял и дебажил. value в renderer со значением null, как в цикле, раза 2-4  проходит, пока не подгрузятся данные и value не станет равна true, false или null.